# WinDirStat sees files that are not there - what's wrong?

Tags: windows, ntfs, chkdsk, windirstat

I've been running WinDirStat to clean up my harddrive. One folder it reports as consisting of 2GB files, and it's also showing these files, but using explorer or the command line, *there is nothing there*.

I've run `CHKDSK /F /V /R` 2 times, but it does not report any errors. What's going on here?

I've gathered some info in a screenshot (a bit german, but you should get the idea):

[image: Screenshot with WinDirStat, cmd and Explorer]

Not sure one can actually read this, so here goes:

- A Folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Alpenverein\Alpenvereinskarten Digital 2010` is shown in WinDirStat containing 2GB worth of map files, but this folder does not show up in cmd or Explorer.
- Opening the properties of a map file, the Common tab shows 50MB size while the details tab shows 0byte size !??
- WinDirStat can open a cmd prompt to this path, although it *apparently isn't there*!?? (`dir .` yields "File or Directory not found") Explorer doesn't show anything (obviously I've checked it to display hidden and system files.)

What's going on here? What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [feature called "Virtual Store"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219276/798677) that is activated when a program tries to save user data to the Program Files folder; it will get saved to the `Users\<yourname>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files` folder.

Check if you have this folder and if the files are there.

Comment: Yup. The Virtual Store helps older programs by silently redirecting writes to the Program Files folder, which requires admin access, to a separate folder.  Safer and helps spot malware.